# How to append counter number to each repeated string value in pandas column?

Tags: python, pandas

Am trying to convert following pandas string column. I just want to append number to each of the repeated case name. As shown below in Expected result section.

```
Index CaseName
0     CASE_A 
1     CASE_A
2     CASE_A
3     CASE_A
4     CASE_A
5     CASE_B
6     CASE_B
7     CASE_B
8     CASE_B
9     CASE_B
10    CASE_B
```

I tried to create a list, which I can replace with current column but length of generated list is large than expected. May be due to nested loops written below.

```py
updatedID=[]
for val in temp_val:
    for cnt in temp_cnt:
        for n in range(cnt):
            updatedID.append(val+str(n))
```

But generated results are wrong.

Expected Result:

```
Index CaseName
0     CASE_A1 
1     CASE_A2
2     CASE_A3
3     CASE_A4
4     CASE_A5
5     CASE_B1
6     CASE_B2
7     CASE_B3
8     CASE_B4
9     CASE_B5
10    CASE_B6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add counter by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html), add `1` and last cast to `string`:

```
df['CaseName'] += df.groupby('CaseName').cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
print (df)
      CaseName
Index         
0      CASE_A1
1      CASE_A2
2      CASE_A3
3      CASE_A4
4      CASE_A5
5      CASE_B1
6      CASE_B2
7      CASE_B3
8      CASE_B4
9      CASE_B5
10     CASE_B6
```